# how to append div to list after adding to mysql db with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to write some data in a mysql database with jquery and ajax. The query works successfully but I am unable to append the data in a div array.

**EDITED:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sub").click( function() {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "insert.php", 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) { 
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#data").append("<div class=\"row\">"
                           +data.position+"  "   //this section must be changed to 
                           +data.text+"  "       // something but I dont know what
                           +data.id+"  "
                           +data.date_added+"  "
                           +"</div>"); 
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#error").html(thrownError);
            }
     })
     return false;
    });

    //disable form redirection
    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
      return false; 
    });

    //clear input fields
    function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
       $(data).val('');
    });
    }

    update();


}); 

function update() {
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "fetch.php", 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(){
                    $("#data").append("<div class=\"row\">"
                                       +this['position']+"  "
                                       +this['text']+"  "
                                       +this['id']+"  "
                                       +this['date_added']+"  "+
                                      "</div>");

                })
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#error").html(thrownError);
            }
     });
     return false;
};
```

How I am going to show the data posted AFTER the query was successful ?

EDIT:

```
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner noRadius">
            <a class="brand" href="#">toDo</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main" class="container">

        <div id="data"> </div>

            <form id="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
                Task: <input class="input-large" type="text" name="text" />
                <br />
                <button class="btn" id="sub">Save</button>
            </form>

            <span id="error"></span>

        </div>

        <!-- Including our scripts -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <link href="library/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="library/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="library/js/ajaxy.js"></script>-->

    </body>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todo");
    $tasks = array();

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
        $tasks[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($tasks);
?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

    include_once('db.php');

    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO todo(text) VALUES('$text')");
    if($query){
        echo "Data for $text inserted successfully!";
        }
    else{ 
        echo "An error occurred!"; 
        }

?>
```

I am trying to build a simple todo application.

I updated insert.php because I was going to insert data into the db with select. I am a beginner and I am trying hard ! Please help me unstuck !

Comment: move the append inside the post callback (function(data){.....)

Comment: We would need to know the response format and what you want to show from it. Also it seems that you are already showing the response inside the #result element, does that display correctly (as expected)?

Comment: yes, it does display but not what I am posting.

Answer (score 1):

Move the append to inside the success callback.. `AJAX` is asynchronous. SO the way you have written the code , the data object is being accessed before the response is populated with the data. So any processing that is to be handled on the response object much be moved to success callback.

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
      $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
              $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
              function(data) { 

               $("#result").html(data);
               $("#data").append("<div class=\"row\">"
                           +data[0]+"  "   //this section must be changed to 
                           +data[1]+"  "   // something but I don't know what
                           +data[2]+"  "
                           +data[3]+"  "
                           +"</div>");
      });
});
```

And the `this[0]` should be `data[0]` assuming that the response is in the form of an array.

It might change based on the response that you expect.

Comment: i get a "S u c c " message, what should that mean ?

Comment: Open the console in developer tools and paste how the response looks like

Comment: it says "Successfully Inserted" so it makes sense , but I have no idea where this message comes from . I am going to post the rest of the files.

Comment: I did a little mistake with the wrong file and corrected it. Now I am getting the first characters of the json array: [ { " i

Comment: Try parsing your json before using it. `data = $.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: I am getting "[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] "

Comment: Noe open the developer tools and click the tab `Network` .. Then try the request again .. You will see the request being sent.. Click on that and then should be response tab..  Paste the object to the question\

Comment: [{"id":"59","position":"0","text":"testing some sh*t","date_added":"2013-07-18 21:35:59"},{"id":"73","position":"0","text":"wergwrgsf","date_added":"2013-07-20 00:16:49"}, etc.

Comment: To access this you would need to use this structure .. `data[index].key` So to get the id of the first object you would do this `data[0].id`

Comment: I am wondering how do you guys learn all that? I am reading and reading and I feel like I know nothing yet.

Comment: Just reading won't help in any way unless you keep using it :) .. It is the same with everyone out there

Comment: I am wondering also where "data" comes from. Having read this from a tutorial, I can't get it because the function's variable (data) isn't called from anywhere :S

Comment: The problem now is that it doesn't seem to post to the database after that. Unfortunately I saw that it appends the last entry and writes nothing in the db. I will update my question with the whole js file.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to echo json data from a SELECT after persisting data to the database

```
if($query){
        $data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE text = '$text'");
        $tasks[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
        echo json_encode($tasks);
        }
```